# How to prevent ignored fields from being returned from Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch, nest, elastic-appsearch

We have an `Elastic Search` engine that has been provisioned through `App Search`, and has a very large schema (large amount of fields). A lot of these fields are not necessary to the scope of our search requests and are returned in the `_ignored` section of the response object. Not only do we not use the `_ignored` data, but they are significantly bloating our response object from Elastic which is not ideal. Is there a way to prevent the `_ignored` section form being returned as a part of the result from a search request?

**Edit**
An example of the request and response
[image]

Comment: Can you please share sample query request you have configured or app search configuration ?

Comment: Sure, added an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_ignored` is metadata field of elasticsearch hence it can not be filter using source filter option.

You need to use [Response Filtering](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#common-options-response-filtering) using `filter_path` parameter in request.

Below is example where it will return only took, _id, _score, _source in search response.

```
POST index_name/_search?filter_path=took,hits.hits._id,hits.hits._score,hits.hits._source
{
  "query": {
    "exists": {
      "field": "_ignored"
    }
  }
}
```